# Tunnel multiple HTTP connections over a bidirectional stream

Tags: socat

I'm looking to forward an http server (on Linux) over a single non-network bidirectional stream (specifically, a QEMU virtio-serial stream, but that doesn't really matter). Basically what I want is:

```
[XXX listen @ 8080] <-> some bidirectional stream <-> [YYY listen on stream, forward to http] <-> [web server:80]
```

The idea is that I want to be able to point a normal web browser (from Linux) at the XXX listening on 8080 and everything would be passed to/from the remote web server via the bidirectional stream and YYY. I can't require root access on the host.

I feel like the XXX and YYY program could be socat (or some other standard tunnel-related program) but it's just escaping me. Any thoughts on the simplest way to go about this?

Answer (score 3):

You want to communicate IP packets over a serial link – great! Luckily, that problem is about as old as IP packets, and has "go-to" solutions:

- [SLIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_Line_Internet_Protocol) if you can stand the lack of automatic configuration, (also: *really* old-fashioned. You probably don't want to use this.)
- [PPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Protocol) if you want it to be able to assign an IP address to either end

Both protocols are meant to encapsulate IP packets through a serial line – and that's exactly what you want here: HTTP connections are actually TCP connections, and TCP runs atop of IP, which already brings the ability to "multiplex" as many different connections over one connection as you want.

So, assuming PPP is your method of choice:

```bash
# on the host machine that has access to the internet
pppd lock proxyarp <host IP>:<VM IP> /path/to/specified/virtioserialsocket

# on the VM
pppd lock defaultroute <VM IP>:<host IP> /dev/virtio-port/<virtioserialdev>

# At this point, you should be able to ping <VM IP>
# from the host, and <host IP> from the VM. If not,
# check `ip route`.
#
# You will now want to set up routing / NAT such that
# either the VM appears as a "normal" computer on the
# network that your host is on, as well, or such that
# all connections to some port are transparently NAT'
# ed over /dev/ppp0 on your host.
# 
# Since that depends on what you're trying to achieve
# here, I can only point out this has been done in a
# lot of other places, and documented.
```

But, honestly. If you have QEMU with virtio, you also can emulate a network card in the guest – and then just do IP through emulated network. That's much easier, more performant, needs no additional software and will work out of the box!

Comment: I'll give that a go tomorrow. I can't use a network card because the thing I'm emulating is a router, and I don't want to mess with it's network config for reasons.

Comment: You'll be messing with its network config either way... To isolate network interfaces, you can just use Linux network namespaces.

Comment: The two primary issues with this solution: (a) seems to require root on the host, which I can't do; and (b) I'm really looking more for multiplexing of direct connections, whereas PPP seems to multiplex arbitrary IP connections, which seems different.

So.. still looking for a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

It does feel to me that the original question is doable somehow via PPP/SLIP, but it didn't really meet my requirements because of too much configuration required on the host. Ideally if socat had a SLIP option and could forward a local port over that, that would be awesome. Alas.

---

Here's a solution that meets my requirements if you assume the host with the HTTP server has an SSH server (and in my case it does):

On the machine with the HTTP server you run socat to forward the virtual serial port to the SSH server (presumably one could use socat to forward an actual serial port as well):

```
socat file:/dev/vport1p1,ignoreeof tcp:127.0.0.1:22
```

The `ignoreeof` option is critical in my case -- if you don't use it the socat just immediately disconnects. Depending on your serial device this may or may not be important.

On the other side of the stream my virtual serial port is just listening on a port on the host (`-chardev socket,id=X,host=127.0.0.1,port=1234` is the QEMU option), so we can connect to it via SSH and do port forwarding that way:

```
 ssh -L 8080:127.0.0.1:80 -p 1234 user@localhost
```

Once the SSH tunnel is established, you can just point your browser at localhost:8080 and it Just Works.